# How do I copy a .eml file when I have the uri?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, webdav

I am using webDAV and .Net 2.0 to gather information on an email account on a server running Exchange Server 2003.  I have access to the uri which looks like this:

```
http://my.mailserver.com/exchange/user/Inbox/someImportantEmail.EML
```

I attempted to copy the file like so:

```
Dim uri As New Uri(uriNode.InnerText)
If uri.IsFile() Then
    Dim fn As String = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath)
    System.IO.File.Copy(uri.LocalPath, "c:\" & fn)
End If
```

But uri.IsFile() is always returning false.  One other thing I noted is that uri.Local path is

```
/exchange/user/Inbox/someImportantEmail.EML
```

I this part of my problem?  How can I copy the .eml file from the exchange server to the local hard drive?

**EDIT:**
I have implemented AnthonyWJones suggestion

```
    Dim cred As New System.Net.CredentialCache
    cred.Add(uri, "BASIC", New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain))
    Dim wc As New WebClient()
    wc.Credentials = cred
    wc.DownloadFile(uri, "c:\testEML.EML")
```

and while this does create the testEML.EML file on my c drive... here are the contents of the EML file:

```
<!--Copyright (c) 2000-2003 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.-->
<!--CURRENT FILE== "NON-IE5" "NON-WIN32" frameset -->
<!--CURRENT TEMPLATE == frameset.00000000 -->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=utf-8">
<TITLE>Microsoft Outlook Web Access</TITLE>
<BASE href="http://my.mailserver.com/exchange/user/">
</HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
var g_iNewWindowWidth = 700;
var g_iNewWindowHeight = 500;
var g_fWarnOnLogOff=false;
function WarnOnLogOff()
{
if (g_fWarnOnLogOff)
alert("To help protect your mailbox from unauthorized access, close all browser windows when you finish using Outlook Web Access.");
}
</SCRIPT>
<FRAMESET OnUnload="WarnOnLogOff()" framespacing="3" cols="190,*"><FRAME bordercolor="#3D5FA3" name="navbar" title="Navigation" src="Inbox/?Cmd=navbar" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" border="1"><FRAME name="viewer" title="Contents" src="Inbox/FW:.EML?Cmd=open" scrolling="auto">
<NOFRAMES>
<BODY><P>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</P></BODY>
</NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

What's with the unauthorized access??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up with that did exactly what I needed.

```
    Dim msgPath As String = message.Path
    Dim msgURI As String = message.URI
    Dim msgID As String = message.ID

    MyCredentialCache = New System.Net.CredentialCache()
    MyCredentialCache.Add(New System.Uri(_inboxPath), "BASIC", New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain))

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(msgURI)
    request.Credentials = MyCredentialCache
    request.ContentType = "text/xml"
    request.Headers.Add("Translate", "f")
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim file As FileStream = New FileStream(msgPath, FileMode.CreateNew)
    Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(4096) {}
    Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

    While (len > 0)
        file.Write(buffer, 0, len)
        len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End While

    file.Close()
    stream.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
 Dim webClient As New WebClient()
 webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
 webClient.DownloadFile(uri, fn)
```

You can't use the standard file IO to copy a http resource